# Using grid div pseudo empty for CSS triangle with before for CSS rectangle

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working with a Joomla template Warp/UIKit template, and trying to create a CSS visual divider to use between two stacked divs with colored backgrounds, such that it would overlay one or both of the colored divs.

I had thought to split this into multiple divs so that I could ultimately have 1) a horizontal band, 2) a down angle and an 3) up angle. I was thinking to interchange the latter two as :before and/or :after,  paired with the horizontal (:empty) div, depending on my other divs. It should be a full-width band 50px tall with, in this example, a centered 50px triangle layered onto the succeeding div.

At this point I have the down angle empty) working where it should be, centered and positioned with the top of the succeeding div and overlaying it nicely.

What I cannot seem to do is get the white (:before) band to display. I've been at this for hours on end, with every combination I can think of and I cannot get it to display at all.

I tend to drive thumbtacks with hammers so am stepping back and hoping someone with a clearer head can point out my error(s).

Thanks much for any advice on this, or if I should just use images for transitioning between colored divs.

```
.uk-grid-divider:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: -75;
left: 150;
right: 150;
height: 50px;
z-index: 0;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
}

.uk-grid-divider:empty {
content: "";
position: relative;
width: 0; 
height: 0;  
top: 75px;
left: 41%;
margin-top: 0px;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-top: 50px solid rgba(255,255,255,.90);
}
```

Comment: could you post an image design for this for a visual design?

Comment: Will this help? https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: I have managed to get some of what I'm after, with a single triangle and nested divs, (although I'm still working to get the background texture to go full-width) here: [site](http://stjuliana.org/academics/curriculum)